# Create a visible frame on SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, frame, sprite-kit, uicolor, skspritenode

Is there a possibility to create a frame on SKSpriteNode?

I would like to do modify SKSpriteNode from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

When I initialize SKSpriteNode I set a color of this sprite:
SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];

Is it possible to add a frame to this node?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in [Kobold Kit](http://koboldkit.com) when "showsNodeFrames" is enabled:

```
if ([KKView showsNodeFrames])
{
    SKShapeNode* shape = [SKShapeNode node];
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(self.frame, nil);
    shape.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);
    shape.antialiased = NO;
    shape.lineWidth = 1.0;
    shape.strokeColor = [SKColor orangeColor];
    [self addChild:shape];
}
```

Basically it creates a SKShapeNode from the node's frame and adds it to the node. In your case substitute `self` with `button`.